# Python - Do I need to remove instances from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

So, in my code I have it create a dictionary from 2 rows in a CSV file, this works perfectly.

However, I randomise a question out of the dictionary for the range of the length of the dictionary. Basically, I was wondering, do I then need to remove/delete this instance(the question) from the dictionary because I have used it because it could randomise it out again, or will a dictionary not randomise a string out twice?

If I do need to remove it how would I go about doing that,

```
import csv
import random
score = 0
# Open file and read rows 0 and 1 into dictionary.
capital_of = dict(csv.reader(open('GeogDatacsv.csv')))
for i in range(len(capital_of)):
    questionCountry = random.choice(list(capital_of.keys()))
    answer = capital_of[country]
    guess = input("What is the capital of %s? " % country)
    print(answer)
    if guess == answer:
        print("Correct, you have scored")
        score +=1
    else: print('Sorry, you have entered an in correct answer')
```

Thanks

Comment: So, you are picking random entries out of a dictionary, and don't want to get the same entry more than once? Then yes, you will need to remove them from the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without destroying your dictionary, by applying [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) on the dictionary's items with `k` set to the length of the dictionary. This will return a list of the items from the dictionary in random order which you can then iterate over.

```
import random

capital_of = {'Australia':'Canberra',
              'England':'London',
              'Indonesia':'Jakarta',
              'Canada':'Ottawa',}

score = 0
for country, capital in random.sample(capital_of.items(), len(capital_of)):
    guess = input("What is the capital of %s? " % country)
    if guess.lower() == capital.lower():
        print("Correct, you have scored")
        score +=1
    else:
        print('Sorry, you have entered an incorrect answer')

print("Score: {}".format(score))
```

**Sample output**

```
What is the capital of Australia? Sydney
Sorry, you have entered an incorrect answer
What is the capital of England? london
Correct, you have scored
What is the capital of Indonesia? jakarta
Correct, you have scored
What is the capital of Canada? toronto
Sorry, you have entered an incorrect answer
Score: 2
```

Comment: So, let me get this straight, random sample just picks a string randomly from the dictionary and doesn't delete/destroy anything, but said string can only be picked once, in the range of the length of the dictionary? Also, how would I go about changing the amount of questions asked from the full length of the dictionary, I would normally have a go at this myself but the syntax of the for loop is unfamiliar to me, thanks a lot though

Comment: Yes, non-destructive and unique (as stated in the linked documentation). You can change the number of questions simply by changing the sample size, i.e. by adjusting the second parameter (`k`) to `sample()`. Using `len(capital_of)` results in _all_ items being returned in random order. If you have say 50 questions, you can ask just 10 random questions selected from the 50 using `random.sample(capital_of.items(), 10)`.

Comment: Alright yeah I get that, thanks a lot for your help, it's greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would need to remove it if you don't want it to be randomly chosen again.

If have selecting a random key from your dict, you could use [`dict.pop`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) for getting the value and removing the item at the same time.  Otherwise, just use `del my_dict[k]`.

Comment: Could you tell me where I would put the del my_dict[k] to make my code most efficient, whilst deleting the questionCountry and the answer from the dictionary, I'll edit it into the main post.

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself first before asking for help again